# Javascript "broken and disabled" in Cargo Collective

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using Cargo to build a website and implementing Javascript on the landing page. I keep receiving an error that says "One or more scripts on this page are broken and disabled". I'm new to JS so I'm not sure if there is actually an error with my code or a glitch with Cargo.

https://codepen.io/222aleon/pen/NWOMrMN

```
// JavaScript code for the slideshow
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
let currentSlide = 0;
let videos = [];

function showSlide(index) {
  slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("active");
  slides[index].classList.add("active");
  currentSlide = index;

  pauseVideos();
  playVideo(index);
}

function setupVideoEndedEvent(video, nextSlide) {
  video.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    showSlide(nextSlide);
  });
}

function pauseVideos() {
  videos.forEach((video) => {
    video.pause();
  });
}

function playVideo(index) {
  const video = videos[index];
  video.play();
}

for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  const video = slides[i].querySelector("video");
  videos.push(video);

  const nextSlide = (i + 1) % slides.length;
  setupVideoEndedEvent(video, nextSlide);
}

showSlide(0);
```

The script is meant to slide through 4 videos and allow the user to click a link for each slide. It seems to work in Codepen but I get an error unless I copy and paste the script enough times in Cargo...